# InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, django

i have the following:

```
class Tag( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=64 )

class Tag2Node( models.Model ):
    ip = models.IPAddressField( db_index=True )
    tag  = models.ForeignKey( Tag )
    last_update = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True )

class Node( models.Model ):
    id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=64 )
    ip = models.IPAddressField( db_index=True )
    method = models.CharField( max_length=64 )
```

(plus some other stuff)

basically i can't do a ForeignKey on the Node.ip as it's rows not unique (i may have may methods for the same ip).

so in order to query i do a

```
found_ips = Tag2Node.objects.filter( tag__name=include ).values('ip').distinct()
q = Q( ip__exact=found_ips[0] )
nodes = Node.objects.get( q )
```

but i get the error:

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

any ideas? cheers,

Comment: What is the value of the variable "include"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from you passing a dictionary to `get`

I'm not sure why this error doesn't throw something else instead...

```
found_ips = Tag2Node.objects.filter( tag__name=include ).values('ip').distinct()
# values returns a dictionary
q = Q( ip__exact=found_ips[0]['ip'] ) 
nodes = Node.objects.get( q )
```

Comment: congrats :)    (15 char minimium)